# Docker swarm networking DNS

Tags: docker, networking, dns, swarm

Cannot resolve service names on different swarm nodes

**Run on manager:**

`docker network create -d overlay --attachable mynetwork`

`docker service create   --replicas 3   --name my-web --constraint "node.role==manager"  --network mynetwork   nginx`

`docker service create  --constraint="node.role==manager" --name my-busybox   --network mynetwork   busybox sleep 3000`

inside busybox on manager node `nslookup my-web` succeeds and finds IP for my-web

`docker service rm my-busybox`

`docker service create  --constraint="node.role==worker" --name my-busybox   --network mynetwork   busybox sleep 3000`

**Run on worker:**

inside busybox on worker node `nslookup my-web` fails to find IP for `my-web`

**Note:**

- When there are replicas of `my-web` on the worker node (no constraints on my-web service) the name can be resolved
- [These ports are open on the machine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts)